# How use this project from GitHub

Tags: android, github, layout, zooming

How can use this [Project](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout)

I add this line on my `build.gradle` file in dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.otaliastudios:zoomlayout:1.0.3'
```

But didn't compile the project. I have this information:
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttYKM.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Regards
Marcin

Comment: Did you try clicking Install Repository and Sync Project  ?

Comment: instead of writing 26.0.0 try 26.+ It will raise warning but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add Google Maven repository to your project build.gradle. On Android Studio 2+:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

On Android Studio 3+:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samuele. Sync process is ok. But when I add code to my xml file i have error: Error:(20, 22) String types not allowed (at 'minZoom' with value '0.7f'). Error:(22, 22) String types not allowed (at 'maxZoom' with value '3f').

Comment: Post me your xml please :)

Comment: <com.otaliastudios.zoom.ZoomLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:overScrollable="true"
        app:overPinchable="true"
        app:minZoom="0.7f"
        app:minZoomType="zoom"
        app:maxZoom="3f"
        app:maxZoomType="zoom"
        app:hasClickableChildren="false">

        <!-- Content here. -->

    </com.otaliastudios.zoom.ZoomLayout>

Comment: Just replace:
`app:minZoom="0.7f"` with `app:minZoom="0.7"`
and
`app:maxZoom="3f"` with `app:maxZoom="3.0"`

Comment: Thank you very much. everything works as it should! :D